# Вывод результата функции во время ее исполнения js

Tags: javascript, массивы

Пытаюсь сделать кату(codewars), где нужно вывести из массива все числа, а строки удалить, написал код

```
function filterlist(l) {
    for (let i = 0; i < l.lenght; i++){
      if (typeof l[i]  == 'string'){
        l.splice(i, 1);
        i--;
      }
    }
    console.log(l); //Если отпрашивать функции тут, я получаю изначальный элемент
  }

 let c = (filterlist([1,2,'a','b']),[1,2]);

console.log(c); //А если тут, я получаю строку уже обработанную.
```

Как я понимаю, по решению каты, нужно сделать return с массивом, когда он уже изменен, но если делать это после исполнение функции, я получаю стартовый массив, а если сделать после функции, я получаю ошибку.

Comment: Не совсем понятно, что вы пытаетесь тут сделать: `let c = (filterlist([1,2,'a','b']),[1,2]);` — этот код вызывает функцию, не использует возвращаемое ею значение, но присваивает переменной другой массив, который следует после запятой.

Comment: Ошибка на самом деле была в l.lenght; чтоб начать получать что либо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас ошибка [Array.length](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length). вы написали `lenght`.

Предлагаю сделать так и не мучатся

```js
let c = [1,2,'a','b'].filter(i => typeof i  != 'string');

console.log(c);
```

а если хотите мучаться то так. Перебирайте массив с конца если удалять из него элементы

```js
function filterlist(l) {
    for (let i = l.length - 1 ; i > 0 ; i--){
      if (typeof l[i]  === 'string'){        
        l.splice(i, 1);
      }
    }
   return l;
}

let c = filterlist([1,2,'a','b']);

console.log(c); //А если тут, я получаю строку уже обработанную.
```

По поводу вывода

```js
function filterlist(l) {
    for (let i = l.length - 1 ; i > 0 ; i--){
      if (typeof l[i]  === 'string'){
        console.log(l);
        l.splice(i, 1);
      }
    }
   return l;
}

let c = filterlist([1,2,'a','b']);

console.log(c); //А если тут, я получаю строку уже обработанную.
```

Comment: Спасибо, да вариант с фильтром видел, но хотелось помучаться)